# How to fix dynamic scroll in Bootstrap search/filter bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a dynamic filter/search bar in Bootstrap 4. I built the search functionality using jQuery and I use values passed from my database. However, the issue I am having is when I type and the selection gets shorter in length, the scroll bar doesn't update itself to shrink. Instead in the search field there is a big empty blank space. I believe it is a CSS issue but I can't seem to find a solution.

**Index.html:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

     <title>UPS Application</title>

     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body>

     <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
             <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">

                     <a class="nav-link" href="/addTyler">Create</a> 
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-md-auto">
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">Account</a>
                     <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
                         <div class="dropdown-divider">
                         </div> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log out</a>
                     </div>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
             <h3 class="text-center">
                 Taddm Mapping
             </h3>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row" id="search-row">

             <div class="col-md-8">
                 <div class="filter-search">
                     <input type="text" id="myInput" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search.."/> 


                         <table class="table table-bordered table-striped list-group" id="myList">
                             <tbody>                      
                               <tr>
                                 <td>Customer Engagement Platform</td>
                                 <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>                             </tr>                      
                               <tr>
                                 <td>Route Target Worksheet</td>
                                 <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>                             </tr>                      
                               <tr>
                                 <td>Crisis </td>
                                 <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>                             </tr>                      
                               <tr>
                                 <td>Empowered to Positively Impact our Customers</td>
                                 <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>                             </tr>                      
                               <tr>
                                 <td>Germany Brokerage System</td>
                                 <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>                             </tr>                      
                               <tr>
                                 <td>Point Management Tool</td>
                                 <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>                             </tr>                      
                               <tr>
                                 <td>Label Applicator Weighing</td>
                                 <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>                             </tr>                      
                               <tr>
                                 <td>Customized Pickup</td>
                                 <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>                             </tr>                      
                               <tr>
                                 <td>Alternate Upload Facility</td>
                                 <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>                             </tr>                      
                               <tr>
                                 <td>Management System</td>
                                  <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>
                               </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Test of a really long string as an examplefor when the others get ablank space</td>
                                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>                              </tr>                      
                                <tr>        
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Test of a really long string as an examplefor when the others get ablank space. Supper long string to show how much i hate coding andf wish I was a stripper</td>
                                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>                              </tr>                      
                                <tr>                  

                             </tbody>
                         </table>


                 </div>
             </div>

         <div class="myForm">
                 <!-- <form th:action="@{/save}" method="POST"> -->
                     <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                             <div class="modal-content">
                                 <div class="modal-header">
                                     <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update or Create</h5>
                                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                     </button>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-body">
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                         <label for="appcode" class="col-form-label">AppCode:</label>
                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="appcode" name="appcode" value=""/>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-footer">
                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="save"/>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 <!-- </form> -->
             </div>

     </div>

 </div>

     <script src="js/script.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

   </body>
 </html>
```

**landing-page.css:**

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */ 
/* HEADERS */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

h3 {
    margin-top: 30px;
}



/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */ 
/* MODAL */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

.modal-dialog{
    overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.selectConfig {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;          /* Configures each select tag to be centered */
}

.form-control {
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;    /* Configures each select tag to have spacing on top and bottom  */
}


.modal-btn {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;

}


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */ 
/* SEARCH FIELD */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

.filter-search {
    width: 100%;
}

.list-group {
    position: absolute;
    height: 600%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#search-row{
    width: 60%;
    margin: 3% 15% 3% auto;
}

#myInput{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

**script.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myList").toggle();

    $("#myInput").on("focus", function() {
      $("#myList").toggle();
    });

    $("#myInput").on("focusout", function() {
      // Here, it'll wait 100 miliseconds to hide the list.
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myList").toggle();
      }, 250);
    });

    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

      $("#myList tr").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
    });

    // This is the code to populate the field after selecting an option.
    $("#myList tr").on("click", function() {
        var texto = $(this).text();
        $("#myInput").val(texto);
      });


  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css code. This will adjust the height according to the content of the div.

```
 #myList {
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... `height: 600%` rules looks very strange.

On the 49's string in your landing-page.css change

```
.list-group {
  position: absolute;
  height: 600%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

to this:

```
.list-group {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```